# Restaurant Menu Items - Locu API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, api

I need help using Locu API. I want to get list of restaurants and their menu items, but it seems like I don't have enough permission. For example, I cannot query data with custom offset/limit, I only get first 25 or 100 items. I get an error message that looks something like this: "Your API key does not have enough privilege,.."

I wonder if I should contact and pay in order to access and query using offset/limits, or is there another way to get all of the data without setting offset/limit values?

Also, I am new to accessing API data, I am not sure how to maintain them. I need to store them in local database, but avoid API rate limits. I should probably update existing database by accessing recently updated data. What should I do in order to do this? Use delayed_job in Rails?

How do I save data to local database? If I create Model instance and does not call .save, it will be stored in my local database?

Thanks for your help.